# Packages - where is the file?

Tags: packages

Where are packages stored in computer (linux)? I can't find it in folders. I would like to send a file.

Comment: `kpsewhere filename` will give you the full path

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `kpsewhich <filename>`, where `<filename>` is the name of the package/class with extension (for example, `latex.ltx`)

Comment: remember to include the file extension (classes are `.cls` and packages are `.sty`) otherwise `kpsewhich` will not fond it

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)